# Yet unsolved problem with Google text to speech voice

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I have a serious worry and problem as I am working with voice over narration (text to speech) and have used a site called VoiceGenerator.io, where I have used a specific female voice called:

Google UK English Female

Just a couple of days ago, I noticed to my utmost sadness, that this voice has changed to a different (horrific low quality voice).
The voice I used was crystal clear, elegant British lady voice.
I cannot understand this any other way, than Google has updated or changed this particular voice because on other free text to speech sites it is the same horrific too.
My simple question is: how can I get back the previous voice? Why was it changed?
How can I obtain the previous voice, no matter what means or costs? Hopefully for free of course as the site I use is free.

Highly appreciate any help regarding this very serious problem, as I need the exact voice to be able to continue my work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through this supported list of voice.

You can hear sample voice also from list.

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices

Comment: Thank you but the specific voice is not there. I confirmed by going through all relevant with comparison to the original.

Comment: Why it happened and where that voice is now, those are the questions I want to find answer. Was it because of 1.Chrome update 2.Win7 update 3.Google voice update